# my else statement is not working properly JS

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
   <!-- some content here -->
   <div id="nav-pc">
                
            <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#my-projects">My Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-prog">About My Job</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
   </div>
```

here is the style of my div

```
   nav-pc {
    background-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

//the first part works well, so after i scroll more than the nav bar is, it becomes fixed.
//but when i return to the top of my page, it don't replace the "fixed" with "relative"
//as it is supposed to, and the bar stay fixed.

```
   window.onscroll = function() {

    var navbar = document.getElementById('nav-pc');
    var nav_position = navbar.offsetTop;

    if (window.pageYOffset >= nav_position) {
    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    navbar.style.position = "relative";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because after it got fixed, the new `navposition` will be indefinitely 0. To fix that, put the variable `var nav_position` outside the function so it won't change through the execution of your app.

```
var navbar = document.getElementById('nav-pc');
var nav_position = navbar.offsetTop; // set once, and won't ever change

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= nav_position) {
    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    navbar.style.position = "relative";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time :), but there is still the problem, now its not working at all.

Comment: @Pulse Then maybe there is more relevant code you didn't show. Can you make a working code snippet? With only what you presented, my test worked.

Comment: im trying to add it into snippet, but the console says: 

"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js"

Comment: I see... Well, add it anyway so I can take a look.

Comment: it keeps saying your post is mostly code, i have been writing like 5 lines explaining and still say so :///